# Converting string to an arithmetic operator

Tags: javascript, java, scriptengine

I have some string that I want to convert in to operators, for which I used

```
Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
string foo=in.nextLine();
ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine engine = mgr.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
System.out.println(engine.eval(foo));
```

I ran and it worked for +,-,/,mod and * but didn't work for any other thing like ^ or !. Does anybody know any way to convert any string to arithmetic.

Comment: `!` and `^`  aren't math  operators. Please provide a [mcve] along with a proper problem statement as per [ask]

Comment: That's because there's no ^ math operator in JavaScript. It's Math.pow(). I would create a switch statement, and provide the operators you want to support.